# Yii2: валидатор «image» не работает на сервере

Tags: php, yii2

**Модель:**

```
namespace app\models;

class TestModel extends \yii\base\Model
{
    public $myImage;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['myImage', 'image', ],
        ];
    }
}
```

---

**Представление:**

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this  object yii\web\View */
/* @var $form  object yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model object app\models\TestModel */

$form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableClientValidation' => false, ]);

echo $form->field($model, 'myImage')->fileInput();

echo Html::submitButton();

ActiveForm::end();
```

---

Я отключил валидацию на стороне клиента:

```
'enableClientValidation' => false,
```

чтобы проверить как валидатор работает на сервере, так как на стороне клиента всё работает отлично; однако на сервере валидатор не работает, то есть пропускает любые файлы?...

---

**Контроллер:**

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use app\models\TestModel;

class TestController extends \yii\web\Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new TestModel();

        if (
            $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
                &&
            $model->validate()
        ) {
            die('Model is valid!');
        }

        return $this->render('index', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: getimagesize на сервере работает?

Comment: @ilyaplot, это что за метод: какого класса?

Comment: **Всё!** Я нашёл причину ... Уже пишу ответ ...

Comment: @ilyaplot, всё, загуглил по [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) :D Первый раз просто работаю с изображениями ...

Comment: В Yii используется функция getimagesize для валидации. Если она не работает, то и валидации для изображений никакой не получится.

Comment: @ilyaplot, спасибо. Может ещё подскажите такой момент: у меня сначала сохраняется модель (AR); потом я создаю директорию, имя которой есть `id` вставленной записи,  и сохраняю туда изображение; а после :) я снова тревожу метод `save()` модели, чтобы сохранить расширение изображения в БД ... При этом вылетает ошибка `getimagesize(...): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. Я понял, что это из-за того, что я тревожу метод `save()` снова ... Это мне говорит, что я выбрал, наверное, неверную методику работы с изображениями ... Может посоветуете какой подход к решению подобных задач?

Comment: Хм... Хотя можно же и сразу сохранить расширение в БД вместе с остальными данными, а после уже сохранять изображение на диск ...

Comment: Используйте, например, beforeSave или afterSave для помещения файла в нужное место.

Comment: Если хочется использовать такой странный метод, как двойной вызов save, второй раз можно вызывать save(false)

Comment: @ilyaplot, спасибо: эти моменты я упустил ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, как обычно — невнимательность! <s>И нежелание разбираться!</s>

---

Всё дело в контроллере ...

Как известно, файлы по приходу на сервер через PHP становятся доступны не в `$_POST`, а в `$_FILES` ... Поэтому, собственно, мы не можем загрузить модель *полностью* так:

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
```

Нам нужно загружать атрибуты, которые представляют собой файлы подобным образом:

```
$model->myImage = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'myImage');
```

Стало быть, перед валидацией нужно полностью загрузить модель:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new TestModel();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->myImage = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'myImage');

        if ($model->validate()) {

            die('Model is valid!');

        }

    }

    return $this->render('index', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

---

Ещё добавлю, что назначать атрибутам (которые представляют собой файлы) данные, нужно после вызова `$model->load()`, так как иначе они будут перегружены (в силу того, что в POST-запросе будет также фигурировать данный атрибут, но пустой).

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам стоит указать расширения файлов.
В [документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#image) имеется пример:

```
[
    // checks if "primaryImage" is a valid image with proper size
    ['primaryImage', 'image', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg',
        'minWidth' => 100, 'maxWidth' => 1000,
        'minHeight' => 100, 'maxHeight' => 1000,
    ],
]
```

Comment: Спасибо, но так тоже не работает на сервере.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov Предоставьте пожалуйста код вашего контроллера и модели

Comment: Поправил вопрос ...

Comment: Нашёл ричину: смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать FileValidator:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4],
    ];
}
```

Подробнее можно посмотреть здесь: [Input file upload](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/input-file-upload.md)

Comment: Я выяснил в чём причина: смотрите мой ответ.